# Extracting typeset lines

Tags: tools, dvi

For a research project, I'd like to extract an image of each typeset line in a page of plain text all in the same font.

I've considered two ways, both hacks of course, but I don't mind hacking:

- Use dvipng and extract the image of each line:
  Probably fragile and hard to get the line heights right.
- Use dvips and hack the PostScript code:
  It seems that `y` signals a new line.

Is there a simple, robust solution?

I control the TeX input completely, if that helps.

Comment: Extract? In what way?

Comment: @Werner, as an image, but PS or PDF works for me as well.

Comment: I wonder if you could use the `geometry` package to make your page height so small that `pdflatex` would only output one line per page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about making each line its own page? Perhaps someone else can show how to make TeX hyphenate across the page breaks the same way it would for regular lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,paperheight=12pt,paperwidth=6.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

this typesets one line per page, producing output like

[image]

then imagemagic convert for example would convert the pdf to one png per page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\a{For a research project, I'd like to extract an image of each
  typeset line in a page of plain text all in the same font. }
\def\b{\stepcounter{enumi}\roman{enumi}) \a\ifodd\value{enumi}\a\fi}
\def\c{\b\b Is there a simple, robust solution? Is there a simple, robust solution?
[\Roman{enumi}] \b\b}

\setlength\textheight{\baselineskip}
\setlength\topskip{0pt}
\setlength\topmargin{-1.1in}
\pdfpageheight60pt
\pagestyle{empty}
\interlinepenalty-10000
\clubpenalty-10000
\widowpenalty-10000
\begin{document}

\c\c\c\c\c

\end{document}
```